# Python, remove all numbers from sublist

Tags: python, string, list, int, character

I have the following list: `[['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S', 3, 7], ['C', 3, 'D']]` (made up of 3 sublists)

But I want to have: `[['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S'], ['C', 'D']]`

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Bahrom how do i format a list?

Comment: Does your list have 3 sublists or 3 strings in it?

Comment: there are 3 sublists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S', 3, 7], ['C', 3, 'D']]
no_numbers = [[item for item in sub_list if not isinstance(item, int)]
              for sub_list in my_list]
print(no_numbers)
```

This prints:

```
[['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S'], ['C', 'D']]
```

Comment: Or `if isinstance(item, basestring)`

Comment: @AlexHall correct, I just wanted to follow along the logic in question, figured `not isinstance int` would work better for removing numbers (integers, I presume, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

This is a code of Python 3:

```
mylist = [['F','G','C'], ['S',3,7], ['C',3,'D']]
rslist = [[y for y in x if not isinstance(y, int)] for x in mylist ]
print (rslist)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mylist = [['F', 'G', 'C'], ['S', 3, 7], ['C', 3, 'D']]
newlist = [[x for x in mysublist if not isinstance(x, int)] for mysublist in mylist]
print newlist
```

There are multiple ways to acheive this. The above example is using list comprehension.

Comment: what if i have sublists? like in the question @sudhishkr

Comment: looks like the question got modified. @abcla - pls check before giving a `-1` :)